# How can I get Firefox to show flash when using wmode="transparent"

Tags: flash, jquery-ui

I have a Flash component that is nested in multiple div's: div1->div2->flashHolder->flashContent. I also have a jQuery modal dialog popup box that warns of upcoming session timeout. Previously, Firefox showed this popup over top of the Flash (correct) while all other browsers hid the popup behind the Flash. To fix this, I added `wmode="transparent"` to the `<object>` tags as well as the `swfobject.embed()` method. This fixed the problem in IE, Chrome and Safari. However, in Firefox, the flashHolder/flashContent div's are now hidden behind div2. I tried setting the z-index of the div's but no luck. So how can I get the Flash component to show with the jQuery dialog box on top in every major browser ?

EDIT: Could not get my Flash object to load in Firefox 4/5 with wmode=transparent or wmode=opaque. It just wouldn't load at all. I think [this](http://mrsteel.wordpress.com/2009/06/05/code-snippets-solving-flash-problem-with-wmode-and-firefox/) page describes the problem, but I decided to fix the problem with a simple javascript hack:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox")==-1)
        params.wmode = "transparent";
```

I know that's looked down upon, but oh well, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `wmode` to `"opaque"`.